# Counting nodes and arcs in BFS Algorithm

Tags: graph, computer-science, graph-algorithm

In DFS you can count the elements by initializating two counters and incrementing them in the DFS-VISIT procedure(+1 node every time the procedure is called and +1 arc everytime that the adjacency list is explored). I was wondering How to obtain the same result in BFS.
This is the BFS pseudocode from Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms", where G is the graph, s is the source node, d is the distance and π is the father node. How can i modify it to obtain the number of nodes and arcs in G?

```
BFS(G, s)
    for each node u ∈ G.V - {s}
        u.color = white 
        u.d = ∞
        u.π = NIL
    s.color = GRAY
    s.d = 0
    s.π = NIL
    Q = Ø
    ENQUEUE(Q, s)
    while Q != Ø
        u = DEQUEUE(Q)
        for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]
                if v.color == WHITE
                        v.color = GRAY
                        v.d = u.d + 1
                        v.π = u
                        ENQUEUE(Q, v)
        u.color = BLACK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, both the adjacency list traversal and new vertex(node) discovery are done in the final while loop of your pseudocode. So, something like the modification given below could work.

```
numArcs = 0
numNodes = 0
while Q != Ø
    u = DEQUEUE(Q)
    numNodes += 1
    for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]
            numArcs += 1
            if v.color == WHITE
                    v.color = GRAY
                    v.d = u.d + 1
                    v.π = u
                    ENQUEUE(Q, v)
    u.color = BLACK
```

Note that if you want to count all the arcs, the incrementation of `numArcs` should be outside the scope of the if statement that follows it, as that if statement is only entered when the destination node is not previously enqueued.

Notice also that this algorithm gives only the number of arcs and nodes in the connected component including the starting node `s`. So, unless your BFS algorithm is modified to handle the case of the graph having multiple connected components, this algorithm will not find out all the nodes and arcs in a graph that is not connected.